# apex CommandButton redirect in Salesforce1

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a problem with Salesforce1 app. I enable the visualforce option to use it in Salesforce1 but when I am using the app and I click in 'Back' Button the app shows the standard navigator view instead de app view (I have attached two images to understand the problem). What can I do?

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CnSendEmailOferta" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<apex:form >
<center>

    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-size: 16pt;color:red;" rendered="{!errorValidacion}">
     Los campos 'Tipo de Oferta', 'Probabilidad de compra','Probabilidad de venta' 'Equipos a ofertar',
        'Fecha de entrada' y 'Limite de presentacion' son obligatorios
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-size: 16pt;" rendered="{!NOT(errorValidacion)}">
    ¿Está seguro que desea enviar el mail?<br></br>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Volver" style="margin-right:30px;margin-top:50px;"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!sendEmail}" value="Send" rendered="{!NOT(errorValidacion)}"/>

</center> 
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference back(){
    PageReference pageRef     = new PageReference(host());
    return pageRef;
}

private String host(){
    String salesforceHost     =  System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();
    String url                =  salesforceHost + '/'+opp.id;  
    return url;     
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For salesforce 1 app ,the way you want to keep the navigation will be using Sforce functions and not use apex pagereference .

With apex pagereference the page navigates to outside the SF1 container leading you to the desktop page .

Take a look at [recommended approach](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm) .The functions are documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm)

You will use `navigateToSObject(​recordId​[, view])` or `navigateToURL(​url​[, isredirect])`